# Trying to create a simple select by attribute script based on an input

Tags: python, attributes, arcgis, feature-selection, arcpy

Trying to create a simple select by attribute script that will select based upon an input in a tool, in ARC Toolbox. My data is stored in a File database in a Feature Dataset called "Control", Feature Class is called "Monuments". Field is called "Township".

Here's the code

```
# Select Features base on Township

import arcpy 

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

Monuments = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Monuments") [0]

TWN = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Monuments, "NEW_SELECTION", "Monuments.Township" = TWN)
```

But getting Error message. "Keyword can't be an expression."

Any thoughts... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting `"Monuments.Township" = TWN` to do as a parameter?

Comment: It's the equation to select all the records in the monument layer that's township = the input parameter.

Comment: But that cannot be a keyword argument

Comment: so what would be the best way to write that argument?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, I've never used `arcpy`. I'm just telling you that, from a basic Python syntax perspective, what you're writing now cannot work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Monuments, "NEW_SELECTION", "Monuments.Township = '" + TWN + "'")
```

**EXPLANATION**

The way you tried it is basically the same as this:

```
whereClause = "Monuments.Township" = TWN
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Monuments, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
```

If you understand Python, you'll recognize that `whereClause = "Monuments.Township" = TWN` is not valid syntax. You cannot assign a value to `"Monuments.Township"`, which is what your code tries to do. In the same way, you cannot pass `"Monuments.Township" = TWN` as a parameter. Instead, you have to build a string, like this: `"Monuments.Township = '" + TWN + "'"`. That is valid syntax, as in the following:

```
whereClause = "Monuments.Township = '" + TWN + "'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Monuments, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
```

My short answer above does the same thing in one line of code instead of two.

(My apologies to Python people, who can probably give a more precise explanation.)